# Small errors accumulate while solving ODE of motion

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the ODE of motion:

$$
\begin{align}
    x''=&\ -myu \frac{x}{r^3} \left(1+\frac{3}{2} {J_2} \left(\frac{{r_{\text{eq}}}}{r}\right)^2 \left(1-\frac{5z^2}{r^2}\right)\right) \\
    y''=&\ -myu \frac{y}{r^3} \left(1+\frac{3}{2} {J_2} \left(\frac{{r_{\text{eq}}}}{r}\right)^2 \left(1-\frac{5z^2}{r^2}\right)\right) \\
    z''=&\ -myu \frac{z}{r^3} \left(1+\frac{3}{2} {J_2} \left(\frac{{r_{\text{eq}}}}{r}\right)^2 \left(1-\frac{5z^2}{r^2}\right)\right) \\
\end{align}
$$

where

$$
\begin{align}
r^2=&\ x^2+y^2+z^2 \\
{J_2},{r_{\text{eq}}},myu &\ \textrm{constants}
\end{align}
$$

I used `RK4`, `RKF5` methods, programmed in Python, also used `odeint` function, `integrate.ode` function with `lsode` and `vode` methods.

All they give small errors, which increase in long time interval. Therefore, in long time interval I get wrong results!

Here is the code of `odeint`:

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.integrate import *

myu=398600.4418E+9
J2=1.08262668E-3
req=6378137

t0=86400*2.3567000000000000E+04
tN= 86400*2.3567250000000000E+04

y0 = np.array([-9.0656779992979474E+05, -4.8397431127596954E+06, -5.0408120071376814E+06, -7.6805804020022015E+02, 5.4710987127502622E+03, -5.1022193482389539E+03])

def f(y,t):
    r2=(y[0]**2 + y[1]**2 + y[2]**2)
    r3=r2**(3/2)

    w=1+1.5*J2*(req*req/r2)*(1-5*y[2]*y[2]/r2)

    return np.array([
        y[3],
        y[4],
        y[5],
        -myu*y[0]*w/r3,
        -myu*y[1]*w/r3,
        -myu*y[2]*w/r3,
    ])


t = linspace(t0,tN)

result = odeint(f,y0,t)

for i in range(0,6):
    print(result[-1][i])
```

Julia code:

```
Pkg.add("DifferentialEquations")
Pkg.add("ODEInterfaceDiffEq")

using DifferentialEquations
using ODEInterfaceDiffEq

myu=398600.4418E+9
J2=1.08262668E-3
req=6378137

t0=86400*2.3567000000000000E+04
tN= 86400*2.3567250000000000E+04

y0 =[-9.0656779992979474E+05, -4.8397431127596954E+06, -5.0408120071376814E+06, -7.6805804020022015E+02, 5.4710987127502622E+03, -5.1022193482389539E+03]

function f(t,y,dy)
  r2=(y[1]^2 + y[2]^2 + y[3]^2)
  r3=r2^(3/2)
  w=1+1.5J2*(req*req/r2)*(1-5y[3]*y[3]/r2)
  dy[1] = y[4]
  dy[2] = y[5]
  dy[3] = y[6]
  dy[4] = -myu*y[1]*w/r3
  dy[5] = -myu*y[2]*w/r3
  dy[6] = -myu*y[3]*w/r3
end

t = linspace(t0,tN)

prob = ODEProblem(f,y0,(t0,tN))

@time sol = solve(prob,Vern7(),abstol=1e-13)

println(sol[end])
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just how small are the errors and how long are the time intervals? (What exactly are the relative errors, can you show the output please?) It's relevant because you've chosen a non-symplectic integrator in odeint, so, for example, non-conservation of energy is to be expected, so the results you're getting might not be "wrong".

Comment: @Kirill For 6 hours (as in the code) the result for x[0] is 1105326.85644, however should be 1092060. I have a test data for comparison.

Comment: This is standard. Any numerical diffeq method has to have errors. For the adaptive timestepping methods, lower the tolerance. There should be a way to do that even with the Python methods.

Comment: Adaptive method RKF5 works very slow, if I did it correctly. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: You mean it goes slow when you need it at a very high accuracy? If you can drop accuracy and if your problem is stiff, `lsode` is a good bet. But it will drop accuracy. I am not quite sure how you can do this fast and keep accuracy in Python. If you're willing to give Julia a try, I would suggest DifferentialEquations.jl with the `Verner7` method. Since your ODE function would compile there, you'll get the benefit of a more accurate method along with faster computations. The problem with Python here is that your `f` is a callback to Python code which heavily slows Runge-Kutta methods.

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: Are you sure Julia would eliminate the problem with errors? What about Fortran with Dopri5?

Comment: It could speed it up. The problem is that every numerical method is going to have errors. You need to be stepping with really small timesteps to "get rid of errors", especially with such large numbers. The first thing you should do is rescale the problem a bit. I am working on an example right now. Could you tell me what the answer you're looking for is? And how accurate?

Comment: 1.0920601198177545E+06; -1.9719312043406873E+06; 6.6852892646843726E+06; -4.0833841182019057E+02; -7.2083121930960815E+03; -2.0579927050199744E+03

Comment: For reference, is that the Python code you were running? When I run that code, I get [9.07638086329e+223; 9.48797814966e-81; 1.04657495534e-312; 2.52059148034e-306; 9.94646703738e+86; 8.48798317088e-313] out of LSODE. It essentially errors due to floating point problems. I don't know how to RKF45 in Python, would like an example to compare against. I'll post in a bit.

Comment: It's the python I run, and it gives results similar to what I mentoned, but with some error. Probably, something is wrong with your Python

Comment: Another option is to use a higher order RK method, if I remember correctly, Julia has at least one order 7/8 method. It may be that the method you're using is just too course

Comment: I have no experience in Julia, could anyone check there my example?

Comment: I'm not convinced that the question here is even clear. Any numerical method introduces an error. What exactly is your goal?

Comment: I need exact calculations for orbit determination. The question is clear enough

Comment: You are asking for exact calculations of a system that may be chaotic (though it looks periodic with these values). These systems can have exponential growth in errors, so you'd need to have extremely high precision values to have anything "exact". Even then, there will be numerical error at some decimal place. And you're comparing it against some "true" value and we have no idea where it comes from, how you got it, and to what precision it was calculated with. That's why this is confusing. At most this is a good demonstration of numerical inaccuracy and chaotic systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, when I ran your code (using LSODE in SciPy) I get

```
>>> result = odeint(f,y0,t)
 lsoda--  warning..internal t (=r1) and h (=r2) are
       such that in the machine, t + h = t on the next step  
       (h = step size). solver will continue anyway
      in above,  r1 =  0.2036188800000D+10   r2 =  0.1292689215500D-07
 lsoda--  warning..internal t (=r1) and h (=r2) are
       such that in the machine, t + h = t on the next step  
       (h = step size). solver will continue anyway
      in above,  r1 =  0.2036188800000D+10   r2 =  0.1292689215500D-07
 lsoda--  at current t (=r1), mxstep (=i1) steps   
       taken on this call before reaching tout     
      in above message,  i1 =       500
      in above message,  r1 =  0.2036188801501D+10
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py:218: ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
  warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)
>>> 
>>> for i in range(0,6):
...     print(result[-1][i])
... 
9.07638086329e+223
9.48797814966e-81
1.04657495534e-312
2.52059148034e-306
9.94646703738e+86
8.48798317088e-313
```

This is what I assume you must mean by the errors. I am not sure why it would do this, but there must be some bad default values for the tolerances, causing the timesteps to go really low with lsode. Multistep methods have to kick start using a low order method like Euler, and so their error estimators are really bad in the first few steps. I think it's going awry there.

I investigated this a bit using DifferentialEquations.jl. It has a bunch of algorithms ready, so it makes it a easier to do this kind of analysis. Setting up the problem is very similar to your Python code:

```
myu=398600.4418E+9
J2=1.08262668E-3
req=6378137

t0=86400*2.3567000000000000E+04
tN= 86400*2.3567250000000000E+04

y0 =[-9.0656779992979474E+05, -4.8397431127596954E+06, -5.0408120071376814E+06, -7.6805804020022015E+02, 5.4710987127502622E+03, -5.1022193482389539E+03]

function f(t,y,dy)
  r2=(y[1]^2 + y[2]^2 + y[3]^2)
  r3=r2^(3/2)
  w=1+1.5J2*(req*req/r2)*(1-5y[3]*y[3]/r2)
  dy[1] = y[4]
  dy[2] = y[5]
  dy[3] = y[6]
  dy[4] = -myu*y[1]*w/r3
  dy[5] = -myu*y[2]*w/r3
  dy[6] = -myu*y[3]*w/r3
end

t = linspace(t0,tN)

using DifferentialEquations
prob = ODEProblem(f,y0,(t0,tN))
```

I don't think much of a comment needs to be said there, since it's almost a straight copy plus changing 0-based indexing to 1-based indexing. First I tried this with LSODA:

```
using LSODA
@time sol = solve(prob,lsoda(),abstol=1e-12)
#0.000690 seconds (17.74 k allocations: 373.578 KB)
println(sol[end])
#[1.20141e6,1.14517e6,7.13797e6,74.8469,-7231.03,1079.12]
```

When I run this with Sundials:

```
@time sol = solve(prob,CVODE_Adams(),abstol=1e-14)
#0.000730 seconds (8.87 k allocations: 187.641 KB)
println(sol[end])
#[1.1016e6,3.68894e6,6.3157e6,513.044,-6351.17,3642.44]
```

It seems like it works out alright. When I use the FORTRAN `dopri` method (this is just a wrapper to the Hairer method):

```
using ODEInterfaceDiffEq
@time sol = solve(prob,dopri5(),abstol=1e-12)
#0.000885 seconds (7.83 k allocations: 180.469 KB)
println(sol[end])
[-965604.0,-1.84395e6,-5.65673e6,-292.419,7785.53,-2437.98]
```

You can see that errors build up more. I checked using [a more modern Julia re-implementation](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/JuliaDiffEq/DiffEqBenchmarks.jl/blob/master/NonStiffODE/Linear%20Work-Precision%20Diagrams.ipynb) of the Dormand-Prince 4/5 algorithm

```
@time sol = solve(prob,DP5(),abstol=1e-12)
#0.000467 seconds (6.82 k allocations: 155.828 KB)
println(sol[end])
[-9.60193e5,-1.96886e6,-5.61328e6,-319.081,7737.2,-2594.4]
```

It seems like this method is just very error prone. I would suggest using newer algorithms, like `Tsit5()` and `Vern7()`. You can see from the benchmarks that I posted that they are more efficient than the old Fortran codes, and I discuss this more [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24998/which-runge-kutta-method-is-more-accurate-dormand-prince-or-cash-karp/25031#25031).

```
@time sol = solve(prob,Tsit5(),abstol=1e-12)
#0.000485 seconds (8.97 k allocations: 218.261 KB)
println(sol[end])
[1.03967e6,-2.41448e6,6.47286e6,-527.843,-7082.73,-2564.45]

@time sol = solve(prob,Vern7(),abstol=1e-13)
#0.001131 seconds (11.19 k allocations: 266.861 KB)
println(sol[end])
[1.10658e6,-1.5227e6,6.79846e6,-369.784,-7333.39,-1590.5]
```

So it looks like the higher order methods (`CVODE_Adams` and `Vern7`) are in the same direction. To see what the correct solution should be, we can re-solve it using higher-precision numbers. Here we will use `BigFloat`s in the algorithms. We can do this just by changing the number types that we build the problem type with:

```
y0_big =big([-9.0656779992979474E+05, -4.8397431127596954E+06, -5.0408120071376814E+06, -7.6805804020022015E+02, 5.4710987127502622E+03, -5.1022193482389539E+03])
t0_big=big(86400*2.3567000000000000E+04)
tN_big=big(86400*2.3567250000000000E+04)
prob_big = ODEProblem(f,y0_big,(t0_big,tN_big))
```

And then solve the problem with higher precision numbers:

```
@time sol = solve(prob_big,Vern7(),abstol=1e-20,reltol=1e-20)
#5.124532 seconds (20.51 M allocations: 1020.807 MB, 29.95% gc time)
println(sol[end]) 

BigFloat[1.1053381662331820146336046671754933670595930944811486000087489128455927171218624720058718205588449974168956065779438050345e+06,-1.5416202537237067975875829305475944291202837487809289389890156042765665624065710316274224354945044382194625246683296005503e+06,6.7926473294913369302731863142467582412609188710382594274952998303466256241086526296652443665837323225497701006408603155527e+06,-3.7312828821058534895294734492513244053231049180643905427777841548594598586886829969951338572602652254542799098196952577885e+02,-7.3297961245134371967675775894582329860535459110035746501350371674509262650960485899126786425646757794442551813929572586948e+03,-1.61096155619704279518364795928351631960055375601824673571833246176656122912319418152730921855088538873761614569864638284e+03]

@time sol = solve(prob_big,Tsit5(),abstol=1e-20,reltol=1e-20)
#46.843028 seconds (202.64 M allocations: 9.848 GB, 21.61% gc time)
println(sol[end])

BigFloat[1.1053381662331820147067348726438400371709496335752162175134992231756774664804231225139143546847966065233311732755080517428e+06,-1.5416202537237067964033929090489735675629358124880169057038770565130982115037191409720907051171224745683301005104028510218e+06,6.7926473294913369306108500165460363424229267867186882151308990443549948472674738460107391298061753478752197008344571867852e+06,-3.7312828821058534874482439660747198554520591273413619386987734456375288506664244304076979140861220572371658224120877522505e+02,-7.3297961245134371970128642262106938950880875625957763378149307834830636800982964288295248480875424454937258559641758284114e+03,-1.6109615561970427939085757874332499247300266093609788206242850106668114350752364680610553537125616823780476995508356156203e+03]
```

This is confirmed by two algorithms at high precision, so this must be the value.

#### Recap

So let's recap a little bit. The timings are really to quick to say much, but at least in Julia there isn't a problem with getting high accuracy. The older methods like `lsoda` and `dopri5` have higher errors. Even `DP5`. Methods and coefficients have been refined since the time these algorithms were made, which is why I wouldn't really recommend them anymore. Sundials and the newer Runge-Kutta methods in DifferentialEquations.jl (OrdinaryDiffEq.jl) are a lot more accurate.

There are a few sources of error that this shows. For one, each method has discretization error, which causes a difference between them. But that should go away with a small enough tolerance. This isn't necessarily the case because of floating point issues, the second source of error. It's a very long timespan, and so you need very low tolerances to not have a substantial buildup of error. This is confirmed by the `BigFloat` results which show that we can only get the first few digits right if we go to much higher precision numbers (tolerances of about `1e-13` without getting junk, and we needed to go lower!).

But lastly, even after going to arbitrary precision numbers, putting a low tolerance, and essentially having two algorithms converge to the same result for the first 10 or so decimal places, we are still off from your proposed "true result". This is likely due to the fact that the initial condition was slightly inaccurate as well, which builds up over time to cause an error in the first digit. The error from the initial condition can grow very fast, so you need to make sure that is very accurate!

(However, I was not able to re-create the SciPy problems here... I am not sure why)

So you need to be careful about all 3 sources of errors, as demonstrated here.

Adding a plot for good measure.

```
plot(sol)
```

[image]

I don't know your problem, but you should always double-check the plot!

#### Can we get around the floating point errors?

The next question to address is, can we get around the floating point errors? Yes, we can rescale the problem. There is no reason to have such large numbers for every number! We can instead move every number down by something like 10^3 by changing units. I would suggest doing a change of units like that in both the dependent variables and time, and see if it can get better results with just `Float64`'s.

But most importantly, I hope this shows a good way to investigate the results.

### Edit: More Verification

Because it was mentioned in the comments, I ran this with

```
@time sol = solve(prob_big,Vern9(),abstol=1e-25,reltol=1e-25)
println(sol[end])

BigFloat[1.1053381662331822596169776849641239592819519884844738459016726262029644062128757651516073415939693720405423642205909058064e+06,-1.5416202537237025194193402796238592848398830150314947716991093949659223769788623589030795132080240499488785780018224381598e+06,6.7926473294913380453538931349439465820220085181755818261687088166926884907951721678701419759674780893612240340931187099615e+06,-3.7312828821058461338614861968657625567908036695262270829525438975640521184553269025483381748908274236026477510068778050456e+02,-7.3297961245134380914206076512518039416894076161354630688132265052545303764963243830516528946565213622293265857749536691384e+03,-1.6109615561970383265735660519068721854582438082504069296606070807069042413835561362598331583440076713255077056006112545402e+03]

@time sol = solve(prob_big,Feagin14(),abstol=1e-25,reltol=1e-25)
println(sol[end])
BigFloat[1.1053381662331822596169777141870567234610511965557086835077483653533437799111462386523440877691562284278052381367094500505e+06,-1.5416202537237025194193397999916272100650863657026496400673463469591815591302649671026419236684086191564320676752769500241e+06,6.7926473294913380453538932693163486282736145849617871379561032756359556363271724242234264204395645390979862595520421289454e+06,-3.7312828821058461338614853616747368391649624257444346156270400632544621072526444156009615705008474094021665763109262437141e+02,-7.3297961245134380914206077511660934608408482056577325775582350370158926687300526721134971356964860345847978865296553096107e+03,-1.6109615561970383265735655400955954012952369987169718357788394884494500522058249689736956400471634474979232165731626140887e+03]
```

So many different algorithms are giving, at very high precision and accuracy, the same result to the first 14 decimal places. Thus for these inputs, this is a value you can trust. If this value is off, then it's the input numbers (the initial conditions, the constants, or the times) which are off.

### Another Edit

We worked it out in the JuliaDiffEq Gitter chat channel. There was an error in the z-acceleration component. The new script is:

```
myu=398600.4418E+9
J2=1.08262668E-3
req=6378137

t0=86400*2.3567000000000000E+04
tN= 86400*2.3567250000000000E+04

y0 =[-9.0656779992979474E+05, -4.8397431127596954E+06, -5.0408120071376814E+06, -7.6805804020022015E+02, 5.4710987127502622E+03, -5.1022193482389539E+03]

function f(t,y,dy)
  r2=(y[1]^2 + y[2]^2 + y[3]^2)
  r3=r2^(3/2)
  w=1+1.5J2*(req*req/r2)*(1-5y[3]*y[3]/r2)
  w2=1+1.5J2*(req*req/r2)*(3-5y[3]*y[3]/r2)
  dy[1] = y[4]
  dy[2] = y[5]
  dy[3] = y[6]
  dy[4] = -myu*y[1]*w/r3
  dy[5] = -myu*y[2]*w/r3
  dy[6] = -myu*y[3]*w2/r3
end

t = linspace(t0,tN)

using DifferentialEquations
prob = ODEProblem(f,y0,(t0,tN))
sol = solve(prob,DP5(),abstol=1e-13,reltol=1e-13)
println(sol[end])

[1.09206e6,-1.97193e6,6.68529e6,-408.338,-7208.31,-2057.99]
```

which hits the true solution dead on. Credit to @crbinz

Comment: Thanks for investigation, however the result should be: ([1.0920601198177545E+06, -1.9719312043406873E+06, 6.6852892646843726E+06, -4.0833841182019057E+02, -7.2083121930960815E+03, -2.0579927050199744E+03])

I tried a lot to get this, but I can't.

My python works fine, giving results similar to yours.

Comment: Are you sure your initial condition is at high enough accuracy? I showed that with really high accuracy the computation for the first component is closer to 1.10e6. You can't change that without changing the problem.

Comment: All the data is given at the highest accuracy. I'm sure, it's possible to solve it, getting required results. I'm looking for a good algorithm

Comment: Why do you think it's possible? I just showed that to about 15 digits of accuracy that is not the solution, given the initial conditions and the constants you have chosen, using 400 bits of precision and an accuracy of `1e-25` with many different algorithms. I showed `Tsit5` and `Vern7` here, but you can use a 9th order method `Vern9` and a 14th order method `Feagin14` and you'll see that they all give the same results in the highest digits at this accuracy. At this point, I am pretty sure that if you get 1.09e6 for the first value with these inputs, that algorithm would have an error.

Comment: What do you suggest now? I have the initial values and have to calculate, getting the result I showed

Comment: Well, either the answer you are looking for is not correct, or the input values are not correct. Those two do not line up. Again, why do you think that the value you're looking for is correct? I would double check how you got it, and if it's from a function, re-run that function at really high accuracy.

Comment: The result value is given as test data.

Comment: May I ask you the full Julia code? Mine says that ArgumentError: DifferentialEquations not found in path

Comment: You need to add the packages before using them. So for anything with a `using` statement, you need to `Pkg.add("PackageName")` to install the package the first time.

Comment: How exactly was the result value calculated from the test data? A better test for this is usually to choose the periodicity and make sure it hits exactly on point. Can you analytically calculate the periodicity for this?

Comment: The result is also the test data. I didn't calculate it. But, I'm sure, it's correct

Comment: Why are you sure it's correct? You have shown no reason to believe that they are valid. How did you calculate those values? And to what precision? It's clearly not the answer for the inputs from your script.

Comment: I have reasons to believe :) It should be the answer for my input data. I'll continue searching, however thanks a lot for your investigation, I'll mark your answer as correct

Comment: The Julia script says ("There is no matching solve()"). But I'm adding the package

Comment: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching solve(::#f, ::OrdinaryDiffEq.Vern7; abstol=1.0e-13)

Comment: Did you `Pkg.add("DifferentialEquations")`, then then `using DifferentialEquations`? Note you have to separately add and using `LSODA` and `ODEInterfaceDiffEq` if you want to try those algorithms (like I showed above).

Comment: Are you passing `f` or the problem type `prob = ODEProblem(f,y0,(t0,tN))`?

Comment: I edited the question and added Julia code. Could you please check?

Comment: Yes, the problem is what I thought. You need to pass the problem type, not `f`, to the solver. `solve(prob,Vern7(),abstol=1e-13)`

Comment: 10 km error for 6 hours for x coordinate :)))) WTF

Comment: Have you used Rosenbrock23? I can't find the documentation

Comment: What about Rosenbrock23? `sol = solve(prob,Rosenbrock23()` gives `[1.08922e6,-1.82755e6,6.72036e6,-419.885,-7287.59,-1896.3]` and `sol = solve(prob,Rosenbrock23(),abstol=1e-13,reltol=1e-13)` gives `[1.10534e6,-1.54162e6,6.79265e6,-373.128,-7329.8,-1610.96]`. This probably isn't the correct method for your problem since it's more efficient for stiff equations. It's documented here: http://docs.juliadiffeq.org/latest/solvers/ode_solve.html#OrdinaryDiffEq.jl-1

Comment: My equation is non-stiff? Are you sure?

Comment: At the accuracy you want, the timesteps for Runge-Kutta methods are not constrained by stability but by accuracy. The RK methods are much faster in this case, which is a sign of non-stiffness. This is using the Shampine definition, which is very practical.

Comment: Thanks! I like Julia, it's very useful, so I'll continue studiing it. However the documentation so good. May I have contact you if I have any questions? Facebook, whatsapp or email, anywhere

Comment: [The DiffEq Gitter chatroom](https://gitter.im/JuliaDiffEq/Lobby) (and the [Julia Gitter chatroom](https://gitter.im/JuliaLang/julia)) is good for chatting. [The issues](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DifferentialEquations.jl/issues) are good for feature requests and bug reports). And [the Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/) is good for longer discussions.

Comment: The dynamics does not seem to be chaotic. The Lyapunov exponents are all zero.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft What's the reason of inaccuracies then?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Do we have symplectic integrator in Julia?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem chaotic. I should've earlier and went to bed. "Do we have symplectic integrator in Julia?", not yet. But maybe I should just get it done.

Comment: Actually, we have `Midpoint`. It's a pretty low order method though.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57161/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-rackauckas-small-errors-accumulate-while-solving-o).

Answer (score 1):

Your dynamics is Hamiltonian. Therefore unlike for dissipative systems, solutions are dense and a numerical error will most likely can kick you from one energy shell to another. If this happens systematically, your solution may slowly drift to a higher or lower energy. While this does not seem to be a big problem here (the solutions I get are pretty periodic on the timescale in question), it may lead to some undesired inaccuracy. If you want to avoid this, you need a symplectic integrator.

Anyway, if you precisely want to predict a periodic dynamics, a long-term integration does not seem like the best approach to me, as a slight error in the period length may destroy everything. You are probably better off determining the period length as exactly as you can (either from experimental data or by finding it with a collocation method or similar) and go from there.

Comment: 1. What are the examples of syplectic integrators? Could you mention any algorithms? Would they help? 2. I am not sure I can determine the period legth. How would it help me?

Comment: I  don't think that is the source of the inaccuracy in question. While it is true that there will be energy drift, non-symplectic integrators will still converge to the correct solution, and so if you use a low enough tolerance then you will still get the correct answer. I showed with pretty high accuracy that a few different methods are converging to a solution different than what @SonyaSeyrios is asking for, suggesting that the error is elsewhere.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas do we have Simplistyc integrator in Julia?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas if yes, could you please add the code of its usage? For example, the midpoint. I'll compare

Comment: 1. *Would they help?* – In your very specific example: probably not. In your general setup: probably. 2. Well, if you really have to predict the motion far into the future and your dynamics is really periodic, you only need to know what one period looks like. Mankind managed to predict eclipses long before they had numerical integrators or even knew what exactly was going on (and that’s a quasiperiodic dynamics).